# gettting error sed: illegal option -- i?

Tags: find, sed, find-and-replace

```
$ find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/original_string/tobereplace_string/g' {} +
sed: illegal option -- i
```

here I'm replacing string using above command but getting error illegal option -- i
can you please let me know what is the issue here
NOTE: i'm executing above command on `UNIX` below is version

```
SunOS Hostname 5.10 Generic_150400-34 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V890
```

Comment: On my Debian Jessie, this works fine.

Comment: You're executing the above command on _what_ UNIX exactly? (AIX? HP-UX? FreeBSD? System V?) Which version, too?

Comment: @grawity SunOS hostname 5.10 Generic_150400-34 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V890

Comment: I'm going to guess Solaris 10, then?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Solaris 10 sed man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/sed-1.html#scrolltoc) page `-i` is not a valid option for sed.

For inline sed usage, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576380/sed-i-what-the-same-option-in-solaris

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f|xargs perl -pi -e 's/original_string/string_to_be_replace/g'
```